# Counting commented characters in a random c file

Tags: c

```
while((x= fgetc(p)) != EOF)
 {
  if (x== '/')
  {
      while((x = fgetc(p)) != EOF && x != '\n' && x != '/')
      {
          comments++;
      }
  }
}
```

Basically all I need is a way to count all the commented symbols in a file. This is the way i tried but it didn't work. Help is much appreciated :).

Comment: comments in c start with `/*` so you should be looking for this not just the single `/`

Comment: And end with `*/`. If you don't check for both characters, you're going to flip state every time you hit division, or the use of `/` inside a string or a comment. And, as Smac89 says, end of line has nothing to do with ending a C comment.

Comment: Adding to my previous comment, You have not given much information apart from `it does not work`. Can't do nothing 'bout that

Comment: do you have to use plain C? I would rather learn Perl that try to reliably perform good pattern matching in plain C. especially if you plan on matching single line comments also... which are now part of the C std

Comment: Fair enough can you show me a way to properly count all the commented symbols?

Comment: @GradyPlayer Yes i do have to use plain C it's for a coursework im doing :/

Comment: I really don't need something that will work flawlessly. I just need something that will work... somewhat ok-ish

Comment: You can search on SO with '`[c] strip comments`' as a search term. You will find a number of discussions. Stripping is similar to counting — you have to identify comments accurately.

Answer (score 0):

here is an example in ruby

```
cProg = %{#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdarg.h>
int main (int argc, char const *argv[])
\{
    printf("Hello World!");//hello world
    /* Some Multi

     Line Comment */

    return 0;

\}
}

matches = cProg.match(/\/\/.*$/)
cStyle = cProg.match(/\/\*[\s\S]*?\*\//)

print matches[0].length
print "\n"
print cStyle[0].length
```

**edit**

just saw that it has to be in C..
you will want to use [strnstr](http://www.gsp.com/cgi-bin/man.cgi?section=3&topic=strnstr) and get the offset from successive `"/*"` and `"*/"` tokens as well as `"//"` to the next `"\n"` and subtract the pointers to get the lengths.

Comment: full disclaimer, I only verified that it worked in this example... and the cStyle isn't greedy

Comment: Thanks I guess. But can you be more specific for they way it can be done in C

Comment: @user3225919 did you look at strnstr()?

Comment: Yes but I don't really get the idea how to use it properly. I'm sorry I am new to programming :/